# show div when another div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying make make a hidden div visible when a div which is on a timer shows up for a promotion. Is is something that is doable? Let me know if the question is unclear i can try to rephrase it

here is some Jquery i have so far

```
$('.specialSignup').css('display', 'none');
    if ( $('.homePromo').filter(':visible'){
        $('.specialSignup').css('display', 'block');
    }
```

Comment: Post relevant HTML and tell us which div you want to show and something code that you have tried.

Comment: @vega-- I added some jquery

Comment: `if ( $('.homePromo').filter(':visible'){` should be `if ( $('.homePromo').filter(':visible') ) { `. You need to close the if condition with the rounded bracket.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995--my bad..i missed that

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to show the first div?
How is it being shown?

Without knowing all the information it's hard to give precise answers, but yes this is definitely possible.
I'm assuming Javascript is toggling the visibility.

Since I'm assuming javascript, I'll take a wager that whatever is triggering the visibility is adding/removing a css class from the div.
In order for the javascript to do that, it needs to find which div needs to toggle.  It's probably looking for a certain id or class that's associated with the div.

Try making the second div have a similar id or class and see if that helps.

If not, I'll need more detail. i.e. what code is triggering the div visibility.

Edit:

Based on the new code you posted, your if statement is missing a end )

It should be this:

```
$('.specialSignup').css('display', 'none');
if ( $('.homePromo').filter(':visible')){
    $('.specialSignup').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: @craig--thanks man..i already resolved it...thanks to jimmy for the quick catch

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

without any additional information..

When the timer times out, trigger either an event or function call to show the hidden layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the display property using: `$(element).is(":visible");`. Should work with `.show()` and `.hide()` as well as `.toggle()` as they affect `display` not `visibility`.